# wireguard - what happens if several peers are using equal credentials / keys

Tags: linux, wireguard

Hello I have a question regarding to wireguard.

What happens if multiple clients (Peers) use the same credentials?

**Example setup:**

- I have a wireguard-server at home.
- I initiate a connection to the server with my smartphone and a minute later with my laptop. Both share the same Private and Public Keys and Wireguard-IP's.

**Possible outcome**

1. None of the clients will be able to access the server.
2. The client that joins last takes over the connection and kicks out the client that joined prior.
3. The server will be able to serve all clients simultaneous?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Peers are *identified by* their keys. You won't be able to add multiple duplicate peers to a server; trying to do so would just update the first peer's configuration.

The 'Endpoint' parameter is **not** used to match inbound packets – even if you configure it manually, that's only used when sending outbound packets. As soon as the server receives a packet that can be recognized as belonging to a specific peer key, it will automatically update that peer's endpoint address so that replies start going to the new address.

This means that if you have two client devices sending packets with the same keypair, the server will either continuously bounce between the two, or will not work at all, but you will *not* be able to use both clients simultaneously.

Comment: So 1. or 2., thank you.

Comment: It's effectively 1, but technically 2, repeatedly, over and over. Each time each client sends a packet, the server will change the endpoint, so if both clients are sending packets, the server will just keep bouncing between the two clients. Imagine if you had two phones but the same person was on both of them, and kept switching between them. "I'm on this phone now..." "now I'm on the other phone..." and you have to keep switching which phone is up to your ear.